# How do I make my wordpress index inside a directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My question is about how to make WordPress' index work inside a directory/folder.

My /public folder contains static pages like index.php, projects.php, etc. I then created a folder for my wordpress, called /blog.

Thing is, /blog doesn't seem to work at all. I've tried changing both WordPress address (URL) and Site address (URL), but got nothing. Its index, that is. All the other wordpress content, such as images, blog posts, are all working. But my /blog index returns an 500 error. How do I fix this?

I would like my website.com/blog to be that good ol' feed with my recent posts, but literally anything will do as long as I get something but a 500 error page.

I don't know if it might have anything to do with my .htaccess on /public, so I'm leaving it here:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"  
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"  
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 https://website.com/404.php
```

Comment: A [500 Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) is literally the "catch-all" of error codes, and could be thrown by just about anything on the server side. I would take a look at your error logs - or turn on [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see what exactly is throwing the error. You could also place `error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` as the first line (after the `<?php`) of your theme's `functions.php` or `index.php` file if `WP_DEBUG` isn't returning anything due to a pre-WordPress error.

Comment: Do you happen to have `blog.php` file? With that rewrite rule in your .htaccess file, `/blog` will load up `blog.php` instead.

Comment: @Xhynk I'll give it a try, thank you!

Comment: @josephting no, not at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure why you got a 500 error and unable to help if you do not share the error logs.

However, you most probably need to add .htaccess into your /blog directory as well.

Try adding `/blog/.htaccess` with the content below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Source: [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

If you share your httpd error_log, then it'll be possible to find out what caused the 500 error.

Comment: It was actually an issue with my index.php inside my /blog, but while turning error logs on to report back at you, I found them out lol thank you!